# Recyclerview doesn't show, with message error No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Ii trying to run the recyclerview, but list item didn't show, and error message is No adapter attached; skipping layout

There is no error with the code, but when try to run, recyclerview doesn't show. Here the main activity, I try to show recyclerview using Parsing Json

```
companion object {
    private val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName
}

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
//    private lateinit var adapter: UserAdapter
private var listUser = ArrayList<DataUser>()


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)


    supportActionBar?.title = "Github User Search"
    binding.rvUser.setHasFixedSize(true)
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    val itemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(this, layoutManager.orientation)
    binding.rvUser.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration)



    searchUsername()
    getDataUser()

}


fun searchUsername () {
    val searchManager = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
    val searchView = binding.searchView

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName))
    searchView.queryHint = resources.getString(R.string.search_hint)
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
            if(query.isEmpty()){
                return true
            } else{
                listUser.clear()
                getSearchUsername(query)
            }
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

    })
}




private fun getSearchUsername(username: String) {
    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    val client = AsyncHttpClient()
    client.addHeader("Authorization", "token<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>")
    client.addHeader("User-Agent", "request")
    client.get(
        "https://api.github.com/search/users?q=$username",
        object : AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            override fun onSuccess(
                statusCode: Int,
                headers: Array<out Header>,
                responseBody: ByteArray
            ) {
                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                val result = String(responseBody)
                Log.d(TAG, result)
                try {


                    val jsonArray = JSONArray(result)

                    for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                        val responseObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                        val userName = responseObject.getString("login")
                        val id = responseObject.getString("id")
                        val avatar = responseObject.getString("avatar_url")

                        listUser.add(DataUser(
                            userName,
                            id.toInt(),
                            avatar
                        ))

                    }
                    val adapter = UserAdapter(listUser)
                    binding.rvUser.adapter = adapter


                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.d(TAG, e.message.toString())
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(
                statusCode: Int,
                headers: Array<out Header>,
                responseBody: ByteArray,
                error: Throwable
            ) {
                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                val errorMessage = when (statusCode) {
                    401 -> "$statusCode : Bad Request"
                    403 -> "$statusCode : Forbidden"
                    404 -> "$statusCode : Not Found"
                    else -> "$statusCode : ${error.message}"
                }

                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity, errorMessage, Toast
                        .LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()

            }


        })
}

private fun getDataUser() {
    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    val client = AsyncHttpClient()
    client.addHeader("Authorization", "token YOUR_GITHUB_API_TOKEN")
    client.addHeader("User-Agent", "request")
    val url = "https://api.github.com/users"
    client.get(url, object : AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        override fun onSuccess(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<out Header>?, responseBody: ByteArray?) {
            binding.progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            val result = String(responseBody!!)
            Log.d(TAG, result)
            try {
                val jsonArray = JSONArray(result)
                for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                    val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    val username: String = jsonObject.getString("login")
                    getSearchUsername(username)
                }


            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<out Header>?, responseBody: ByteArray?, error: Throwable?) {
            binding.progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            val errorMessage = when (statusCode) {
                401 -> "$statusCode : Bad Request"
                403 -> "$statusCode : Forbidden"
                404 -> "$statusCode : Not Found"
                else -> "$statusCode : ${error?.message + " GIT"}"
            }
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
        }

    })
}

}
```

And here the adapter

```
class UserAdapter(private val listDataDetailUser: ArrayList<DataUser>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ListViewHolder>() {


private lateinit var onItemClickCallback: OnItemClickCallback


fun setOnItemCLickCallback(onItemClickCallback: OnItemClickCallback) {
    this.onItemClickCallback = onItemClickCallback

}


override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ListViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.item_profile_list, viewGroup, false)
    return ListViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val data = listDataDetailUser[position]

    Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
        .load(data.avatar_url)
        .into(holder.avatar)

    holder.username.text = data.login




}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = listDataDetailUser.size

inner class ListViewHolder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    val avatar: CircleImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.img_profile)
    val username: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_username)



}

interface OnItemClickCallback {
    fun onItemClicked(data: DataUser)
}


}
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You have not added LayoutManager to your Recyclerview.
Try adding LinearLayoutManager which you have created for your ItemDecoration.

```
binding.rvUser.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```